# How to lock a field based on user role?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, business-rules

The old way I've always done it was to trigger a script on load and set the fields to this or that (hiding, locking etc.). But since we got those new, cool, shiny business rules now, I thought I could give them a whack.

The problem is that I can't figure out how to specify a condition based on the current user's role... Where is it hiding?!

Comment: You should accept Guido's answer.

Comment: @Sean Yes, I should. Not sure why I missed it so it's a great thing that you've pointed it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are not hiding because they don't exist. Business rules have a limited set of capabilities and they can't check the role of the users.

If you just need to lock the field Field Level Security can be an alternative, but for CRM 2013 you can only use on custom fields.

However good old JS + Plugin enforcement is (in my opinion) the preferred way.